# Looking for Netsuite WSDK Documentation

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I have taken over development of a website that integrates with Netsuite.  The main way that it seems to use to get information from Netsuite about the current session (ie cart details, etc) is through the use of Javascripts.  For example

```
http://shopping.netsuite.com/app/site/query/getcartitemcount.nl?c=xxxxxxx
```

gets the number of items in the cart (where c is my clients company id).

I have been trying for hours to find some kind of documentation for these as I need to get back some extra information and just can't seem to find anything useful.  Does anyone know where I can find docs for these?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case anyone else is stuck hunting for these, they are in netsuite and can be found by going Setup -> Website -> Preview Website

You will see 2 links under the heading 'External Catalog Site Tools'.

'Links from your site back into NetSuite UK' will give you a list of checkout and cart related links.

'HTML and URLs for querying items' will give you a list of all the products you have set up.  Click into one and you will see the different formats available for retrieving product information.

Hope this helps someone else

Answer (score 0):

Log into your Netsuite account and click the help link. Or check the [Developer resources](http://www.netsuite.com/portal/developers/dev-resources.shtml) on the netsuite homepage.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Unfortunately I've spent quite a bit of time looking through those already with no joy